# How to response to client with BigData using Protocol Buffer RPC call?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, rpc

I Have two application that communicate with each other via Rpc the first one is the client the second is the server. I use [protocol rpc pro](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro/). Now, as it is [stated in google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#large-data)  it is not designed for big data transfer. My question is how do I transfer a big data a response to RPC call comming from server ?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Google documentation you link, you need to split your data up into smaller pieces.  Maybe make several RPCs, one to get each chunk.  Note that this has other advantages, e.g. you can display a progress bar that updates after each chunk.  Some RPC systems also support some sort of "streaming" feature where one RPC call can receive multiple responses.  (I am not familiar with the particular RPC system you linked.)

Comment: Yes this is what actually I am looking for, the multiple responses you are mentioned !